# NSAppearanceNameAqua is returned both in dark and light mode

Tags: xcode, macos, qt, macos-darkmode

I have an application in Qt for mac and after upgrading to XCode 11.4, my application does not switches to dark mode.

I checked out my code and I realized that NSAppeareance name is NSAppearanceNameAqua both in case of light and dark mode.

I tried the following two ways:

```
NSString * appearance = NSAppearance.currentAppearance.name;

NSString * appearance = NSApplication.sharedApplication.effectiveAppearance.name;
```

Anyone else faced the same issue?

Comment: Yes, I've experienced the same issue after upgrading. Didn't know how to fix it and downgraded Xcode to 11.3 for now. Sorry that I can't help but wanted to mention that you're not the only one with that issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the Qt folks are already working on it, see [QT-BUG83111](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-83111).

Comment: Yes, and they just closed it.